# jQuery what is - el.moveDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

based on this code in the link https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/how-i-built-the-one-page-scroll-plugin/

```
function init_scroll(event, delta) {
   var deltaOfInterest = delta,
   timeNow = new Date().getTime(),
   quietPeriod = 500;

   // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
   if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + settings.animationTime) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
   }

   if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
      el.moveDown()
   } else {
      el.moveUp()
   }
   lastAnimation = timeNow;
}

$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
   init_scroll(event, delta);
});
```

What is `el.` part before it calls `moveDown()`? I'm new to jQuery and I'm not sure what it's called.

It can also be seen calling `swipeEvents()`.

```
el.swipeEvents().unbind("swipeDown swipeUp");
```

Cheers

Comment: [Based on their code](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/blob/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js#L126) I'd say it's the current element wrapped in jQuery.

Comment: We can't know from the code you gave, it is maybe a global variable, or a variable defined in parent scope. It can be anything since also `moveUp()` or `moveDown()` aren't jQuery functions so that we can talk about the type of `el`.

Comment: Yep thanks. The el object has been declared int he settings variable at the top of the code. I totally missed this! Pretty confusing name since i'm new to jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their [example](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) code shows:

```
var el = $(this)
```

Where this is the element that plugin is initialized on:

```
 $(".main").onepage_scroll();
```

Putting a breakpoint in the `init_scroll` function and inspecting `el` shows:

```
[<div class="main onepage-wrapper" ... > ... </div>]
```

Which is indeed the jQuery selector over the element that the plugin was initialized on.

Comment: But hasn't el only been declared in the scope of moveDown()? 

EDIT: oh wait nvm, i totally missed the declaration also in the settings variable at the top. silly me, now it makes a lot more sense.